# Liferay Portlet - form name with namespace, getParameterMap missing parameters

Tags: forms, liferay, portlet, liferay-6

I am using Liferay 6.2, i am having a form as below in jsp

```html
<form name="<portlet:namespace/>"
    action="<portlet:actionURL windowState='normal'>
               <portlet:param name='action' value='processAction'/>
            </portlet:actionURL>"
    method="post">
    Value: <input type="text" name="prpValue" />
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

And in the corresponding processAction method i am using

`actionRequest.getParameterMap();` which does not have the prpValue parameter?

What is missing here?

Note: i can not use actionRequest.getParameter() with namesapce, becuase my generic logic is, in such a way that i need to get all parameters.

Answer (score 4):

Try

```
Value: <input type="text" name="<portlet:namespace/>prpValue" />
```

This properly namespaces the parameter and it will be directed to your portlet. The actual parameter can be read as

```
actionRequest.getParameter("prpValue");
```

so the `PortalRequest` parameter handling already removes the namespace

---

*Edit*: As you say it doesn't work for you, this is what worked for me: Plain portlet with these implementations:

```
@ProcessAction(name="go")
public void go(
        ActionRequest request, ActionResponse response)
    throws IOException, PortletException {

    StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();

    Map<String, String[]> pm = request.getParameterMap();
    for(String key:pm.keySet()) {
        result.append(key).append(": [ ");
        String[] value = pm.get(key);
        if(value != null) {
            for(String val:value) {
                result.append(val).append(" ");
            }
        }
        result.append("]<br/>");

    }

    response.setRenderParameter("PM", result.toString());
}
```

and view.jsp like this:

```
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/portlet_2_0" prefix="portlet" %>
<portlet:defineObjects />
Testportlet 

<form action="<portlet:actionURL name='go'/>" method="post">
    <input name="<portlet:namespace/>test" type="text" value="testing"/><br/>
    <input type="submit"/><br/>
</form>

<hr/>
<%=renderRequest.getParameter("PM") %>
```

Comment: Thanks Olaf Kock, even if i add namespace in the input tag, still actionRequest.getParameterMap(); does not have prpValue. getParameter() method works fine but i am facing issue with getParameterMap() method.

Comment: And you can use ParamUtil.getString(actionRequest, "prpValue");

Comment: But my logic is based on getParameterMap() [getting all parameters from portlet and passing to other system.]. So need to use getParametermap() method

Answer (score 0):

I was also getting stuck on this. The solution is simple.
Add `<requires-namespaced-parameters>false</requires-namespaced-parameters>`
to your liferay-portlet.xml -> portlet entry.
This is a change of version 6.2.
[There is official detailed explanation](https://issues.liferay.com/browse/LPS-44604)